# unusual result in Mysql Date Comparison

Tags: mysql, date

I have a `datetime` datatype in my table,

```
 `DateAdded` datetime(4) DEFAULT NULL,
```

I have a record in my database with `DateAdded = 2017-09-11 17:02:48.6531` value, ( it's ID = 16452994 ).

When I want to get it with following query return NULL

```
select `ID`,`DateAdded` from `Add` where   `DateAdded` <= FROM_UNIXTIME(('1505071799' +86400 ), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') and ID =16452994 ;
```

FYI :  FROM_UNIXTIME(('1505071799' +86400 ), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') = `2017-09-11 23:59:59`

It's strange that `2017-09-11 17:02:48.6531` <=  `2017-09-11 23:59:59` return **false**

but when I try the following query I'll get my desire result.

```
select `ID`,`DateAdded` from `Add` where   `DateAdded` <= FROM_UNIXTIME(('1505071799' +86400 +1 ), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') and ID =1645299;
```

I want to know why this is happening and how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: What is the configured time zone on your server?

Comment: @Pred thanks for your attention. it's not related to server timezone, I resolved it with generate via FROM_UNIXTIME(('1505071799' +86400 ), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')

`H` instead `h` :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp), FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp,format)
>
> Returns a representation of the unix_timestamp argument as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' or YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu format, depending on whether the function is used in a string or numeric context. **The value is expressed in the current time zone.** unix_timestamp is an internal timestamp value such as is produced by the UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function.
>
> If format is given, the result is formatted according to the format string, which is used the same way as listed in the entry for the DATE_FORMAT() function.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

Comment: I resolved it with generate via FROM_UNIXTIME(('1505071799' +86400 ), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')

`H` insted `h` :|